# Is there a circuit that 'blocks' or 'opens' another circuit as long as there is current running?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design

I want to make a light source that runs by main power and only uses batteries when there is a power outage.

Note: Please explain in simple terms, since I'm just a middle school student.

Comment: search for "change power supply battery" on here. Literally dozens of answers  already :)

Comment: You could, of course, buy a maintained emergency light which does just what you want.

Comment: But mains produces electricity at 240VAC whereas batteries produce DC electricity at something way lower. There must be something you're forgetting to include here. Perhaps a transformer? I don't believe a light source can produce light at such drastically different voltages, let alone that one is direct current and the other is alternating current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is called a *relay*.  That's a mechanical switch that is activated by a electro-magnet.  When power is applied to the magnet, the switch is one way.  When power is removed, the switch goes the other way.

Relays come in a variety of switch configurations.  A very common one is *single pole, double throw* (SPDT).  That means there is one center connection that is connected to one of two outer connections, depending on whether the magnet is energized or not.

You want to have your AC power drive the magnet, and the battery power connected thru the *normally closed* (NC) connection.  In this case, "normal" refers to no power applied to the magnet.  That switch is closed (meaning it conducts) when there is no AC power.  When AC power is present, the switch opens, and the battery is disconnected.

Relays are available with a large variety in what it takes to power the electro-magnet.  In your case, you want a relay that is intended to be run from whatever your line power is.  That would be a 115 VAC at 60 Hz here in North America, for example.

Comment: I recommend you edit to emphasize the fact the the relay must have a 110 or 220 (as appropriate) coil rating. If the poster finds a 5 volt unit and plugs it in....

Comment: @What: Done. --

Answer (score 1):

Use a relay. There exists plenty of types which accept mains AC for control and have both opening and closing contacts. Searc for "relay" to learn the principle. That component really was a basic building block for automation 100 years ago and it still is due its robustness.